# What is the soundtrack when Neo kisses Trinity in Matrix Reloaded?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

What is the soundtrack when Neo kisses Trinity in Matrix Reloaded.
It has loud organ music in the background.

Link:
https://youtu.be/ujNhcRv_pRY

Last 20 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [TheLethalCarrot on SciFi SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/218750/73606) accepted answer:

This is part of the *Matrix Reloaded Suite* by Don Davis. I'm no music expert so comparing the notes was a bit awkward but I think it is around the 15 minutes 20 seconds mark in the song.

https://youtu.be/nTiCGbNcwb8?t=920